# How can Split a String value by PHP?

Tags: php, split, character, cpu-word

i have a string like this :

```
$string = 'LatLng(35.700585, 51.377027)';
```

how i can select first section between '(' and ',' character?

Like :

```
$x = '35.700585';
$y = '51.377027';
```

help . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
<?php
$string = 'LatLng(35.700585, 51.377027)';
$newStr = str_replace('LatLng(', '', $string);
$newStr = str_replace(')', '', $newStr);

$arr = explode(',', $newStr);

$x = $arr[0];
$y = $arr[1];

print_r($y);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$str = "LatLng(35.700585, 51.377027)";
echo $x = explode(',', str_replace(')', '', str_replace('LatLng(', '', $str)))[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP | explode() Function: The explode() function is an inbuilt function in PHP which is used to split a string in different strings. The explode() function splits a string based on a string delimiter, i.e. it splits the string wherever the delimiter character occurs.